# Render method firing 2 times in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, react-router

I have a room in which I have some messages. So the model is

```
{
  createdAt: Date,
  messages: [String]
}
```

I fetch my room with

```
class Room extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { room: {} };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchRoom();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    let oldId = prevProps.params.roomId
    let newId = this.props.params.roomId
    if (newId !== oldId) {
      this.fetchRoom();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.ignoreLastFetch = true;
  }

  fetchRoom() {
    if (!this.ignoreLastFetch) {
      const roomId = this.props.params.roomId;
      socket.emit('get room', roomId, room => {
        this.setState({ room: room });
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.room.messages); // debug

    const roomId = this.state.room._id;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Id: {roomId}</h2>
        <p>Created at: {this.state.room.createdAt}</p>
        <h2>Messages</h2>
        <Messages roomId={roomId} messages={this.state.room.messages} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that `render()` is both called **before** I have fetched the room and **after** I have fetched the room, so it results in 2 calls.

Can't I wait to fire `render` until I have fetched the room since I don't care about seeing an empty room?

It also seems that since I am using `<Messages roomId={roomId} messages={this.state.room.messages} />`, it sends an empty array of messages. If I debug in the `render()` method with `console.log(this.state.room.messages)`, it first prints undefined and then it prints the array of messages (i.e. 2 calls).

Comment: In react, render will be called immediately after (or before?) component is mounted and after you call `setState`. That is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `render` will be called after component is mounted, but there is a way not to render component until you have the data you need. [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render) defines how to solve this:

> You can also return null or false to indicate that you don't want
>   anything rendered.

Let's take advantage of this in the render method:

```
render() {
    // check if the room is set
    if(!this.state.room){
        // room is not set, return null so that nothing is rendered
        return null;
    }

    // happy path - render the room
    const roomId = this.state.room._id;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Id: {roomId}</h2>
        <p>Created at: {this.state.room.createdAt}</p>
        <h2>Messages</h2>
        <Messages roomId={roomId} messages={this.state.room.messages} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place this logic in "shouldComponentUpdate" and not within the Render method. The render method should be pure and you should not be placing any logic within them. Also returning null from a Component may have site effects on the Virtual Dom.

Comment: What logic should I place in `shouldComponentUpdate` rather than `render`? Are there any alternatives to returning `null`?

Comment: The render method with be called if, shouldComponentUpdate returns true. This allows you to perform simple and complex checking of props v previous props. This allows you to return "true" if you know that the change required a write to the "real" dom. This means that React will not over render.